# Figure out word values

Tags: mathematics, word

Given `ooze, noon, tone, snooze, onset, stone, tones, fees, toffee, noses, sneeze, sense, stetson, festoons, nonsense` are all legal words, and are worth `10, 20, 23, 32, 36, 36, 36, 38, 40, 44, 46, 51, 54, 59, 70` respectively, what English word with three letters is worth only `2`? What is `tenseness` worth?

Comment: Can words have negative values?

Comment: @Areeb No - only positive integer values.

Comment: Is there any significance to the fact that "snooze" and its corresponding 32 are listed twice?

Comment: Uh, snooze is in there twice?

Comment: no,stone listed thrice....

Comment: I think it is there to show that it always returns the same value? Onset, Stone, and Tones are all anagrams and have the same value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word worth 2 is

> Zoo

Because

> $e = 8$
>  $f = 9$
>  $n = 9$
>  $o = 1$
>  $s = 13$
>  $t = 5$
>  $z = 0$
>  And all values are added together.

Tenseness is then worth:

> $5 + 8 + 9 + 13 + 8 + 9 + 8 + 13 + 13 = 86$

Found by the following:

> $tone = 23$, $stone = 36 \rightarrow s = 13$
>  $ooze = 10$, $snooze = 32$, $snooze - ooze = sn = 22 \rightarrow n = 9$
>  $noon = 20 \rightarrow oo = 2 \rightarrow o = 1$
>  $noses = 44 \rightarrow e = 44 - 9 - 1 - 13 - 13 \rightarrow e = 8$
>  $ooze = 10 \rightarrow z = 10 - 1 - 1 - 8 \rightarrow z = 0$ 
>  $fees = 38 \rightarrow f = 38 - 8 -8 -13 \rightarrow f = 9$
>  $tone = 23 \rightarrow t = 23 - 1 - 9 - 8 \rightarrow t = 5$

As explained by the OP:

> **z**ero $\rightarrow$ = 0
>  **t**wo $+$ **t**hree $\rightarrow 2 + 3 = 5$
>  **f**our $+$ **f**ive $\rightarrow 4 + 5 = 9$
>  **s**ix $+$ **s**even $\rightarrow 6 + 7 = 13$
>  **e**ight $\rightarrow$ = 8
>  **n**ine $\rightarrow$ = 9

Comment: Are you sure S = 13? I got S = 3. Do you mind showing your work?

Comment: @AggieKidd Too easy! Yes, values: z: **z**ero (0), o: **o**ne (1), t: **t**wo + **t**hree (5), f: **f**our + **f**ive (9), s: **s**ix + **s**even (13), e: **e**ight (8), n: **n**ine (9)

Comment: beautiful!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

It's like calculating a system of linear equations but simpler

> [image]